# Compute angles between joints in hand landmarks using c++

Tags: python, c++, numpy, angle

I'm trying to calculate the angles between joints that comes from hand landmarks to feed my LSTM hand gesture model, I have the python version of the code and I want the c++ version of it

```
if result.multi_hand_landmarks is not None:   
        for res in result.multi_hand_landmarks:

            joint = np.zeros((21, 4))
            for j, lm in enumerate(res.landmark):
                joint[j] = [lm.x, lm.y, lm.z, lm.visibility]

            # Compute angles between joints
            v1 = joint[[0,1,2,3,0,5,6,7,0,9,10,11,0,13,14,15,0,17,18,19],    :3] # Parent joint
            v2 = joint[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20], :3] # Child joint
            v = v2 - v1 # [20, 3]
            
            # Normalize v
            v = v / np.linalg.norm(v, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]

            # Get angle using arcos of dot product
            angle = np.arccos(np.einsum('nt,nt->n',
                v[[0,1,2,4,5,6,8,9,10,12,13,14,16,17,18],:], 
                v[[1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10,11,13,14,15,17,18,19],:])) # [15,]
            
            # Convert radian to degree
            angle = np.degrees(angle) 

            d = np.concatenate([joint.flatten(), angle])
            seq.append(d)

            if len(seq) < seq_length:
                continue 
            input_data = np.expand_dims(np.array(seq[-seq_length:], dtype=np.float32), axis=0)
            
            interpreter.set_tensor(input_index, input_data)
```

I managed to do most of the work

```
for(auto mark:hand_results.joint){
        joint.push_back({mark.x,mark.y,mark.z,mark.visibility});
    }

    std::cout << "\n joint.size "<<joint.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\n joint.size "<<joint[0].size() << std::endl;
    
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> Q_joint = {
        {0,1,2,3,0,5,6,7,0,9,10,11,0,13,14,15,0,17,18,19}, 
        {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}
    };
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> Q_angle = {
        {0,1,2,4,5,6,8,9,10,12,13,14,16,17,18}, 
        {1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10,11,13,14,15,17,18,19}
    };

    std::vector<std::vector<float>> v;     
    for(int i=0; i<Q_joint[0].size();i++){
        int q1  = Q_joint[0][i];
        int q2  = Q_joint[1][i];
        float tem1 = joint[q2].at(0) - joint[q1].at(0);
        float tem2 = joint[q2].at(1) - joint[q1].at(1);
        float tem3 = joint[q2].at(2) - joint[q1].at(2);
        v.push_back({tem1,tem2,tem3});
    }
       
    // // v.size == 20*3
   
    float nor1=0;
    float nor2=0;
    float nor3=0;
    
    for(int j=0; j<v.size() ; j++){
        nor1 += abs(v[j].at(0));
        nor2 += abs(v[j].at(1));
        nor3 += abs(v[j].at(2));
    };

    nor1 = sqrt(nor1);
    nor2 = sqrt(nor2);
    nor3 = sqrt(nor3);

    for(int j=0; j<v.size(); j++){
        v[j].at(0)= v[j].at(0) / nor1;
        v[j].at(1)= v[j].at(1) / nor2;
        v[j].at(2)= v[j].at(2) / nor3;
    }
    // Compute angles between joints
    for(int i=0 ; i<Q_angle.size();i++){
        // TODO:
    }
```

but I got stoked on getting angle using Arcos of dot product block.
I have two questions first how can I apply **np.einsum nt,nt->n** in c++ vector. second is there a better way to do this instead of using loops?

**[UPDATE]:**
I solved the np enisum by doing this, Now I just want a way to avoid the loops or at least make the at minimum?

```
std::vector<float> angles;
for(int i=0 ; i<Q_angle[0].size();i++){
    int q1  = Q_angle[0][i];
    int q2  = Q_angle[1][i];
    float tem1 = joint[q2].at(0) * joint[q1].at(0);
    float tem2 = joint[q2].at(1) * joint[q1].at(1);
    float tem3 = joint[q2].at(2) * joint[q1].at(2);
    
    float arcos= acos(tem1+tem2+tem3);
    // convert form radian to degree
    float degree =  arcos * (180 / M_PI);
    angles.push_back(degree);
}
```

Comment: For a "better way", you can use some linear algebra library (e.g. `Eigen`) with simple operations already implemented. It might be slightly faster than a classical loop if it's possible to take advantage of some SIMD instructions, however in such a simple example I don't think that speed is an issue. For this Einstein sum, I don't understand which operation it does in your example, please explain. Finally, python "easy" array operations with numpy is just a syntactic sugar, it still needs to loop over the elements under the hood.

Comment: With `numpy` we try to avoid loops because they are performed at interpreted speeds.  Instead we try to use compile numpy methods.  They still loop, but in fast compiled code.  In C++ it's all compiled.

Comment: Is there a way to use NumPy functions in c++ to avoid the loops, I know that must of the NumPy code is C based for that shouldn't be like NumPy C++ API to be able to use the same function in both languages.